# c++ why priority_queue greater<> result is different from sort`s greater result?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I searched for similar contents, but I don't understand the answer, so I'm asking you again.

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(11);
v.push_back(13);
v.push_back(-1);
v.push_back(-8);
v.push_back(324);
v.push_back(55);
sort(v.begin(),v.end(), greater<int>() );
for(auto i : v)
{
    cout << i << " ";
}
```

// result is descending order

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> pq;
pq.push(3);
pq.push(5);
pq.push(4);
pq.push(9);
pq.push(13);
pq.push(15);
while(!pq.empty())
{
    cout << pq.top() << " ";
    pq.pop();
}
```

// result is ascending order

also greater`s implementation is here

```
struct greater : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
{
  _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR
  bool
  operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
  { return __x > __y; }
}
```

x > y means descending, but why?? why especially in priority queue greater means ascending? Plz someone clarify this clearly.. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this `std::priority_queue` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> A priority queue is a container adaptor that provides constant time lookup of the **largest** (by default) element

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So the default sorting using `std::less` is descending. By using `std::greater` you reverse that. ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is defined like that. The previous answer is good, but I'd put some more emphasis on one more part of the [specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

> Note that the Compare parameter is defined such that it returns true
> if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak
> ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements
> first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last. That
> is, the front of the queue contains the "last" element according to
> the weak ordering imposed by Compare.

So in case of "greater" it means "small first".

Comment: Note also that you are removing elements from the priority queue via "pop" but printing elements in the vector front to back. If you used `pop_back` to print the vector, they would agree again: Both would print descending. So the discrepancy is also self-inflicted. One side is using pop and the other isn't.